# replace string based on array items loop in php

Tags: php

On my website, I have comments.

In my comment string, I find all username mentions like so (username mentions start with /u/, for example `/u/felix`):

```
preg_match_all('#/u/([a-z0-9]+)#i', $comment, $matches);
```

Now I have an array of usernames called `$matches`.

I want to then replace all username matches in `$comment` with something like this:

```
<a href="/u/felix">/u/felix</a>
```

I tried doing a foreach solution with a str_replace, however I run into the problem of having users that contain the usernames of other users. So if we had the users "fel", feli" and "felix, the loop would do it 3 times for "fel".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to extract the usernames, just replace them all at once with a single regexp:

```
preg_replace( '#(/u/[a-z0-9]+)#i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $comment );
```

No need to worry about similar usernames since each will be matched and replaced without affecting the others.

Comment: There is no need for any capture groups.  `$0` will work just fine.  And no need to answer duplicate questions for that matter.